# MPI - EXIT CODE: 139

Tags: c, mpi, mpich

I face this error code in a single node mpi but there are systems that do not encounter that by compiling the same code.

**Maybe its a mpich installation issue? Could that be the case?**

It wouldn't be a good idea to post the code here, since it's not that small.

The thing is, as I mentioned, it works in "real" distributed system, but when compiled in my laptop(single node) I get this error code.

> ===
> =   BAD TERMINATION OF ONE OF YOUR APPLICATION PROCESSES
> =   EXIT CODE: 139
> =   CLEANING UP REMAINING PROCESSES
> =   YOU CAN IGNORE THE BELOW CLEANUP MESSAGES
> =================================================================================== YOUR APPLICATION TERMINATED WITH THE EXIT STRING: Segmentation fault
> (signal 11) This typically refers to a problem with your application.

Comment: yeah, a tool like 'valgrind' will point to the problem area.  Or maybe you got a core file?  look at the back trace.   MPICH does explode sometimes if used improperly but we try pretty hard to do something sensible with bad inputs.

Comment: @dreamcrash yes but how can the same code work in a distributed system and not work in my single node mpi?

Comment: I mean, I've tested multiple codes, and they work on the distributed system of my university but it won't work on my laptop. I get this error...running exact same programs.
It has to be installation problem, but i've clean installed twice. @dreamcrash

Comment: that doesn't help. Thank you though.